# How to do perform deep clone for data migration from one Datalake to another using databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm attempting to migrate data from Azure Data Lake to S3 using deep clone. The data in the source Data Lake is stored in Parquet format and partitioned. I've tried to follow the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/clone-parquet.html) from Databricks, which suggests that I need to register Parquet tables with partitions in a catalog such as the Hive metastore before cloning. However, I encountered an error while attempting to execute the clone command.

First, I created a table in the target Data Lake with the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customerOrderArchive (
column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
...
)
PARTITIONED BY (batchid string)
LOCATION 'targetPath/temp';
```

This table was successfully created in the catalog.

Then, I attempted to execute the clone command as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE cdf.customerOrderArchive
CLONE parquet.`sourcePath/customerorder/`
```

However, this resulted in the following error:

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 381.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 381.0 (TID 2488) (10.139.64.15 executor 0): com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.DeltaAnalysisException: Expecting 0 partition column(s): [], but found 1 partition column(s): [`batchid`] from parsing the file name: abfs://pathToSource/batchid=20240123235612633/part-00000-tid-792802563625641899-725c22de-6f96-439a-927b-f4e70648de3a-42-1.c000.snappy.parquet
```

Despite creating and registering the table in the Spark metadata catalog, I'm still encountering this error.
Can anyone provide insight into what might be causing this issue? Additionally, is it possible to migrate data from one Data Lake to another using deep clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the same [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/clone-parquet.html#requirements-and-limitations-for-cloning-parquet-and-iceberg-tables), it is mentioned as follows:

> You must register Parquet tables with partitions to a catalog such as the Hive metastore before cloning and using the table name to identify the source table. **You cannot use path-based clone syntax for Parquet tables with partitions**.

This means if you have a source parquet table that is partitioned, you cannot use the below syntax to clone the partitioned parquet table which is registerded in hive metastore:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <target-table-name> CLONE parquet.`/path/to/data`;
```

Instead, the suggested way would be:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE <target-table-name> CLONE <source-table-name>;
```

or

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE cdf.customerOrderArchive CLONE <source-table-name>;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. How do I provide the source table name when it's in different datalake? will be able to figure out that by itself?

Comment: Is it not possible to get the source table that is hosting the data in this path `parquet.<sourcePath/customerorder/>` ? Another option would be to read the source table's data using the `abfss:<path_to_source>` using dataframe reader & then using the dataframe writer to save the results to S3.

Comment: I mean, I can get the table name. But the way how we enter is something is schemaName.TableName right? How do we inform the spark that this table is on another data lake's metastore catalog. The reason why I want to clone instead of read-write is cause I red clone is more performant than spark's batch way of reading and writing

Comment: Also with the clone, how do I provide path for external table? I see when I give LOCATION as parameter it throws error. May be Clone doesn't support this? Does this always create managed table?

Comment: I believe `CLONE` does not support cloning external tables across cloud (Azure to S3) directly as such. The most performant would be using either ADF to migrate the files first and then run a create table command on top of the target structure in S3 that was migrated.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this very lately. Thanks for your help man. Appreciated.

Comment: So, let's say we are cloning in the same datalake. Even in this case it doesn't support cloning to external tables?

Comment: Within the same cloud service (AWS or Azure), cloning external/managed tables should be possible and not an issue.

Comment: Can you please let me know how it can be done? I created a table using the LOCATION and later I tried to run a clone. But as per the syntax it's CREATE or REPLACE TABLE not CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXSIT